# Cannot query fields on allMarkdownRemark graphql

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

## Goal

Hi. I have a Gatsby website and I am making use of the `gatsby-transformer-remark` plugin to get a load of blog markdown files from a blog directory into GraphQL to display on my site. I have looked at the docs and example code to see how to create a slug for each page so that in the `gatsby-node.js` file I can create pages with the slug dynamically.

### Issue

When I try to access the `fields { slug }` property in GraphiQL I get the following error:
`message": "Cannot query field \"fields\" on type \"MarkdownRemark\"."` I have checked my setup a couple of times and I think it all seems good so I'm not 100% sure what I have missed to not have these fields. I can access other informations such as the raw content of the markdown files and the frontmatter data, just not the fields.

### Code

In My `gatsby-config.js` plugins I have the following setup for the source filesystem and the remark plugin

```
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `blog`,
        path: `${__dirname}/blog`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-transformer-remark`,
      options: {
        plugins: [
          {
            resolve: `gatsby-remark-images`,
            options: {
              maxWidth: 960,
            },
          },
          `gatsby-remark-prismjs`,
          `gatsby-remark-copy-linked-files`,
        ],
      },
    },
```

Once I am in GraphiQL I run the following query to replicate the error

```
query {
  allMarkdownRemark(
          sort: { fields: [frontmatter___date], order: DESC }
          limit: 1000
        ) {
    edges {
      node {
        fields {
          slug
        }
        frontmatter {
          title
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see, `slug` field is not a child of `frontmatter` (as natively should if you work with raw markdowns). To make the `slug` available as children of `field`, you need to add the following snippet in your `gatsby-node.js`:

```
const { createFilePath } = require(`gatsby-source-filesystem`)

exports.onCreateNode = ({ node, getNode, actions }) => {
  const { createNodeField } = actions
  
  if (node.internal.type === `MarkdownRemark`) {
    const slug = createFilePath({ node, getNode, basePath: `pages` })
    createNodeField({
      node,
      name: `slug`,
      value: slug,
    })
  }
}
```

Adding this configuration with [`createNodeField`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/actions/#createNodeField) API you are allowing Gatsby and the inferred GraphQL schema to create additional fields on nodes created by other plugins by telling Gatsby that if the node type is a markdown, create a `slug` field based on the `slug` value of the `frontmatter`.

You can check for further information in [Gatsby's docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/creating-slugs-for-pages/).

Comment: Thankyou very much, I knew it would be something minor that was being missed out. Had me stumped for a while this one